# How to manage woocommerce subscription with api?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm trying to get all subscriptions from php with this code:

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

    $woocommerce = new Client(
            'https://www.magazzinoperfetto.it', // Your store URL
            'ck_c92b6b6452XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
            'cs_e3380e1c07XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
            [
                'wp_api' => true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
                'version' => 'wc/v2' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
            ]
    );

    print_r($woocommerce->get('subscriptions'));    
?>
```

If I use the api with woocommerce product etc... it's functionally. But with the subscription I receive this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException' with message 'Error: Nessun percorso fornisce una corrispondenza tra l'URL e le modalità di richiesta [rest_no_route]' in /var/www/vhosts/magazzinoperfetto.it/httpdocs/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php:324 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/magazzinoperfetto.it/httpdocs/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php(349): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->lookForErrors(Array) #1 /var/www/vhosts/magazzinoperfetto.it/httpdocs/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php(385): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->processResponse() #2 /var/www/vhosts/magazzinoperfetto.it/httpdocs/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/Client.php(82): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->request('subscriptions', 'GET', Array, Array) #3 /var/www/vhosts/magazzinoperfetto.it/httpdocs/change-sottoscrizione.php(22): Automattic\WooCommerce\ in /var/www/vhosts/magazzinoperfetto.it/httpdocs/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php on line 324

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to create the new endpoint like `get_subcription` and create the once callback function with this function you can write your code for the get subscription and return it from the callback function.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'custom_api_endpoints' );
function custom_api_endpoints () {
  register_rest_route( 'wc/v2', 'get_subcription', array(
    'methods'  => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'custom_subscription_endpoint_handler'
  ) );
}
function custom_subscription_endpoint_handler () {
    return $woocommerce->get('subscriptions');
}
```